# Whats the thread return address on the stack?

Tags: c++, multithreading, assembly

I'm using ZwCreateThread to create a thread in VS C++ win64 native, and i almost have it working, except when my thread executes the ret instruction in assembly i get an access violation, because i have not put a return address on the stack, so my program trys to execute code at memory location 0

obviously this will not work. So the question is what address does CreateThread and CreateRemoteThread put on the stack?

I was thinking i could use the address of ExitThread function.
Would this be appropriate?

Also, the target processor is AMD64

Comment: Just by curiosity, no pun intented, why not using _beginthread/ex?

Comment: @manuell The only case I can think of where somebody needs to use an undocumented API like this (instead of using the documented API) is if they are writing malware and are trying to avoid detection.

Comment: @RaymondChen I am happily and completely ignorant on the subject. Starting a thread is a red flag?

Comment: @manuell Starting a thread by using an undocumented API is a red flag, since you're clearly trying to hide the fact that you're creating a thread. If you were an honest person, you would just use the documented APIs `CreateThread` or `CreateRemoteThread` or the equivalent runtime functions `_beginthread/ex`.

Comment: As i have stated just now in one of my other threads, this is for a debugging driver, that supports multiple functions. CreateThread just happens to be one of the many functions i have been working on implementing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows `ret` instruction should terminate the thread properly. Probably your code breaks the stack in some way. Although, calling `ExitThread` should work even in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason ZwCreateThread Sets the Rsp register to (tContext.Rsp - 0x30)
If someone has any information on why this might be happening, please share!

I solved this by doing the following.

```
tContext.Rsp = (DWORD64) ((unsigned long long)BaseAddress + RegionSize - 8);
*(PULONG64) ((unsigned long long)BaseAddress + RegionSize - 0x38) = (unsigned long long) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("kernel32"), "ExitThread");
```

Comment: SOLVED! The 0x30 bytes that ZwCreateThread creates on the stack is for storing the parameters that are passed via the 64-Bit registers.